# why can't I express 10 power 10

Tags: c++

I tried to express 10 power 10 but it didn't work, so I thought the problem is the range of the data type.

Finally I changed the type from int to `__int64` but it isn't yet working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, r, n;

    __int64  d;

    cin >> a; //  a=10
    cin >> r; //  r=10
    cin >> n; //  n=10

    d = a * pow (r, n - 1);

    cout << int(d);
}
```

My expected answer is 10000000000 but result of the operation is 1410065408

What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you converted the answer to an `int` with `cout << int(d)`, and the answer doesn't fit in an `int`.

Comment: In `<cstdint>` there is `std::int64_t`, which is a portable way of getting a 64 bit signed integer if one exists, instead of `__int64`.

Comment: Also, don't mix float and int. Use a for loop and multiply by ten ten times

Comment: Woah, thanks, @francois, good to know

Comment: Thank you every one .

Comment: you can also write 1e10

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no, all overloads with integer exponent [has been removed since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). The only overload the accepts integral values also casts the value internally to floating-point types: *7) A set of overloads or a function template for all combinations of arguments of arithmetic type not covered by 1-3). **If any argument has integral type, it is cast to `double`. If any argument is `long double`, then the return type Promoted is also `long double`, otherwise the return type is always `double`.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert `__int64` into `int` which can't hold values like `10000000000` in the `cout` statement.

Don't confuse between `__int64` (holds 8-bytes data) and `int` (holds 4-bytes data). Simply remove the conversion `int()`.

Comment: Thank you sir I really appreciate

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,n;

    long long int  d; //change the type to long long int


    cin >> a;
    cin >> n; //  n=10

    d =  pow (a, n );

    cout << d;

}
```

The problem was the range of your data type. By changing to "long long int" you'll get the expected answer 10000000000.

Comment: `long long int` is not likely to be larger than `__int64` and a 64 bit integer is definitely large enough already anyway. You've removed the cast from the `cout` which is why you get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you sir I really appreciate

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score -3):

Use powl(a,b) instead of pow(a,b) for large integers as in your case.

Comment: Thank you sir I really appreciate

Comment: @Hamp  But some intellectuals down voted my first answer

Comment: because your "answer" is wrong. It has nothing to do with pow or powl. The issue lies in `int(d)` where an int can't store such a huge number